# Como usar uma API em C++?

Tags: c++, embarcadero

Andei pesquisando em diversos sites que explicam como utilizar uma API, mas, por algum motivo estou fazendo errado.
Gostaria de saber como devo utilizar a API WM_PASTE, do Windows, para bloquear o Paste do mouse(ctrl+v) num TComboBox. Estou usando Embarcadero C++ Builder.

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: declarei a windows.h e tentei usar algumas funções windows procedure, mas não compilava nada. fiz algumas declarações na .h do meu form como havia pesquisado, mas, n tive resultado. empaquei aí e pensei: to fazendo tudo errado.

Comment: Resposta direta: [Leia a documentação da API em questão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você pergunta "Como utilizar uma API" você esta perguntando uma API qualquer, ja que existe muitas como Win32 API, DirectX, OpenGL e muitas outras.

Você quis dizer como utilizar o Win32 API? Correto?

WM_PASTE não é uma API e sim uma diretiva de compilação que é usada como constante no Win32 API que representa 0x0302 hexadecimal.

E aparentemente você esta utilizando outra API gráfica, então é necessario conhecer a API que você esta utilizando para saber se é possivel fazer isso apenas com a API que você esta utilizando. Se realmente você precisar usar o Win32 API será necessario ter acesso ao HWND (Handle WiNDow) do controle TComboBox que é o manipulador do controle, e acesso ao loop de mensagens do programa.

Comment: muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento. estou a recém começando a estudar sobre APIs do windows. então ainda estou meio perdido por onde começar.

Comment: Se essa resposta te ajudou podia meter como reposta certa, não?!

Comment: Mesmo sua resposta não resolvendo meu problema, me esclareceu mts coisas e realmente me ajudou a melhorar minhas pesquisas. e sim, minha ferramente é uma jossa. só utilizei-a em vista da solicitação de meu professor no curso. obrigado!